# Gdal_grid gives blank .tiff file after conversion

Tags: gdal, convert, geotiff-tiff, vrt

After using `gdal_grid` I get blank .tiff file. I use the following `.vrt` file :

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="p">
      <SrcDataSource>p.csv</SrcDataSource> 
      <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType> 
      <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_1" y="field_2" z="field_3"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

and my data is in following format :

```
318600.00,323600.00,640.00
318575.00,323525.00,639.73
318550.00,323475.00,644.10
318625.00,323575.00,645.10
```

I use the following command parameters for `gdal_grid` :

```
$ gdal_grid -l p p.vrt p.tiff
Grid data type is "Float64"
Grid size = (256 256).
Corner coordinates = (313814.744746 323793.349824)-(319085.945254 318715.120176).
Grid cell size = (20.510508 19.759648).
Source point count = 18922.
Algorithm name: "invdist".
Options are "power=2.000000:smoothing=0.000000:radius1=0.000000:radius2=0.000000:angle=0.000000:max_points=0:min_points=0:nodata=0.000000"

0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

This is the resulting [.tiff file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwc5yjwjy21v6rd/p.tiff)

**EDIT**

This is the info returned from `gdalinfo`

```
**Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: p.tiff
Size is 256, 256
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (313825.000000000000000,318725.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (20.510507812500009,19.759648437499891)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  313825.000,  318725.000) 
Lower Left  (  313825.000,  323783.470) 
Upper Right (  319075.690,  318725.000) 
Lower Right (  319075.690,  323783.470) 
Center      (  316450.345,  321254.235) 
Band 1 Block=256x4 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem to be blank. Probably your viewer just can not show that Float64 type file in a reasonable way.

```
gdalinfo p.tiff -stats
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: p.tiff
Size is 256, 256
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (313825.000000000000000,318725.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (20.510507812500009,19.759648437499891)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  313825.000,  318725.000)
Lower Left  (  313825.000,  323783.470)
Upper Right (  319075.690,  318725.000)
Lower Right (  319075.690,  323783.470)
Center      (  316450.345,  321254.235)
Band 1 Block=256x4 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=476.461, Maximum=1013.430, Mean=721.370, StdDev=107.204
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1013.4300537109
    STATISTICS_MEAN=721.36974261562
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=476.46142578125
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=107.20396608821
```

Comment: I have also checked it with `gdalinfo` and I have basically the same results as you do but when I open it with image viewer (I use EyeOfGnome) I see an empty tiff file.

Comment: Geotiff might be too much for a normal image viewer. Take QGIS for a change. The tif looks beautiful ;-)

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. I used QGIS 2.4 and everything is ok now:) thanks